# How to calculate custom fiscal year in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
app_date
20/3/2017
28/8/2017
18/10/2017
15/2/2017
2/5/2017
11/9/2016

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Our company fiscal year is from `October` of current year to `September` of next year

```
Q1 - Oct to Dec
Q2 - Jan to Mar
Q3 - Apr to Jun
Q4 - July - Sep
```

I was trying something like below

```
tf['app_date'] = pd.to_datetime(tf['app_date'])
tf['act_month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(tf['app_date']).month
tf['act_year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(tf['app_date']).year
tf['act_qtr'] = tf['app_date'].dt.to_period('Q').dt.strftime('Q%q')
tf['comp_fis_year'] = np.where(tf['act_month'] >= 9,tf['act_year']+1,tf['act_year'])
tf['comp_fis_qtr'] = tf['app_date'].dt.to_period('Q').add(1).dt.strftime('Q%q') #thanks to jezrael for this trick to get quarter
```

Is there any elegant and efficient way to do the above? Mainly for calculating the fiscal year based on our financial year `(Oct to Sep)`?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Your input seems to be inconsistent with your output. The 4th first dates are `dayfirst=True` and the 2 last are `dayfirst=False`

Comment: how is that `dayfirst` is taken? because I just manually typed those records with month values in 2nd position. I ask because, mext time, I can provide input correctly

Comment: If you typed with month values in 2nd position: `11/9/2016` should be `2016-09-11` and not `2016-11-09`. IMO.

Comment: last row should be Q4 (11 Sept)

Comment: @TheGreat please check the Quarters start/end in my answer and correct your question ;)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. When I meant 2nd position for month, I did `df['app_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['app_date']`, then as per this 2nd position becomes month, which is 11th month (Q1)

Comment: @TheGreat then this is just a detail from your side, I believe my answer is correct, just make sure to have the correct dates as input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, use [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) with a [custom frequency](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.qyear.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['app_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP')
```

output:

```
0    2017Q2
1    2017Q4
2    2018Q1
3    2017Q2
4    2017Q3
5    2016Q4
Name: app_date, dtype: period[Q-SEP]
```

for separate columns:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['app_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP')
s.astype(str).str.extract('(?P<year>\d+)(?P<quarter>Q\d+)')
```

output:

```
   year quarter
0  2017      Q2
1  2017      Q4
2  2018      Q1
3  2017      Q2
4  2017      Q3
5  2016      Q4
```

Q start/end:

```
df['Q'] = pd.to_datetime(df['app_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP')
df['Qstart'] = df['Q'].dt.asfreq('D', 's')
df['Qend'] = df['Q'].dt.asfreq('D', 'e')
```

output:

```
     app_date       Q      Qstart        Qend
0   20/3/2017  2017Q2  2017-01-01  2017-03-31
1   28/8/2017  2017Q4  2017-07-01  2017-09-30
2  18/10/2017  2018Q1  2017-10-01  2017-12-31
3   15/2/2017  2017Q2  2017-01-01  2017-03-31
4    2/5/2017  2017Q3  2017-04-01  2017-06-30
5   11/9/2016  2016Q4  2016-07-01  2016-09-30
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help, but your output is incorrect. guess you pasted incorrect column. not sure

Comment: @TheGreat then I guess you need Q-SEP

Comment: Can check my updated output now? I think the updated output format is easy to understand the month and days

Comment: I liked `str.extract` with named groups :D

Comment: You can also use `df['Q'].dt.qyear` as a quick way to extract the fiscal year

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# Create 2 DatetimeIndex instead of a Series (avoid using .dt accessor)
start = pd.to_datetime(df['app_date'].values, dayfirst=False)
end = start + pd.DateOffset(months=3)

cols = ['act_month', 'act_year', 'act_qtr', 'comp_fis_year', 'comp_fis_qtr']
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([start.month, start.year, 'Q' + start.quarter.astype(str),
                           end.year, 'Q' + end.quarter.astype(str)],
                           index=cols).T)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     app_date act_month act_year act_qtr comp_fis_year comp_fis_qtr
0   3/20/2017         3     2017      Q1          2017           Q2
1   8/28/2017         8     2017      Q3          2017           Q4
2  10/18/2017        10     2017      Q4          2018           Q1
3   2/15/2017         2     2017      Q1          2017           Q2
4    2/5/2017         2     2017      Q1          2017           Q2
5   11/9/2016        11     2016      Q4          2017           Q1
```

Setup:

```
app_date
3/20/2017
8/28/2017
10/18/2017
2/15/2017
2/5/2017
11/9/2016

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Comment: the output for last row is incorrect

Comment: I updated my answer with fixed input data. Can you check it please?